# PostgreSQL insert into from select but ignore existing rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert data into a table from a select. This works fine so far...

```
INSERT INTO table_2
    SELECT t.id, 1
        FROM table_1 t
        WHERE t.title LIKE '%search%';
```

But when I run this a second time, the statement raises an exception, because some of the rows already exist.

What can I do to get around this?

Thanks for your help,
Urkman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can insert rows where they don't already exist, by adding that as a clause.

```
insert into table_2
select t.id, 1
  from table_1 t
 where t.title like '%search%'
   and not exists (select t2.id from table_2 t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```